# Heroku: Papertrail Log not showing detailed version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm running my Rails API app on Heorku server and using Papertrail as an add-on.

While working I'm able to see the log but those are limited to one line for each request and doesn't show the detailed consisting of the queries and other logs which is easily visible on our local environment.

I have already set the following config:
`config.log_level = :debug` in my Rails project

and

`heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` on heroku server.

But then too hardly any success. Any help! Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in production.rb instead of

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

place:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

More Details:

> Some frameworks send log output somewhere other than stdout by
>   default. These might require extra configuration. For example, when
>   using the Ruby on Rails TaggedLogger by ActiveSupport, you should add
>   the following into your app’s configuration to get stdout logging:
>   config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Thanks ! Saved a lot of time :)